# defining global constant in angularJS in ionic v1 app

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an ionic v1 app and I want to save my url as a constant or string globally and use it anywhere in the app as required.How to do this??

Answer (score 1):

```
appname.constant('CONSTANTS', {
    TEMPLATE_PATH: {
        LOGIN: {
            LOGIN_PAGE: 'app/Auth/template/log-in.html',
            //balance
        }   
        }
    }
```

this is a ameple format how we define a constant and you can use it any time as

```
templateUrl: CONSTANTS.TEMPLATE_PATH.LOGIN.LOGIN_PAGE
```

keep each module separated like Login,Home..etc for better use

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file "constants.js" and make a self calling function that instantiates each constant you declare there as an angular constant.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function constants() {
        return {
            'SERVER': {
                url: 'http://' + ip_back_end + ':' + porta_back_end + '/' + name_app_back_end
            }
        };
    }

   // I'm using lodash here, but you can do it the same way as angular foreach
    _.forEach(constants(), function(value, key) {
        angular.module('app').constant(key, value);
    });
})();
```

Then in any other angular component, you can inject it

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, SERVER) {
  $scope.tasks = [
    { title: 'Collect coins' },
    { title: 'Eat mushrooms' },
    { title: 'Get high enough to grab the flag' },
    { title: 'Find the Princess' }
  ];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it worked:

```
app.constant('configSettings', {
  'baseUrl': 'http://www.google.com',
  'someElseSetting': 'my new Value'
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, configSettings){
  console.log(configSettings.baseUrl);
  $scope.baseUrl = configSettings.baseUrl;

});
```